# Add item's to list dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, list

So i am trying to take input item's in list , but it is adding only one item.

What am i doing wrong

```
public void AddItems(List<Things> thing)
 {
    Console.Write("\nEnter Product ID : ");
    int choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("\nEnter Quantity : ");
    int quantity = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    var item = thing.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ID == choice);

   if (item.ID == choice)
     {
       List<SelectedThing> selectedthing = new List<SelectedThing>();
       {
          var total = item.Price * quantity;
          selectedthing.Add(new SelectedProduct(this.ID = item.ID, this.Price = item.Price, this.Quantity = quantity, this.Name = item.Name));
          foreach (var items in selectedthing)
           {
             Console.WriteLine("\nYou Selected {0} and {1} quantity.Total Is {2:C}\n", items.Name, quantity, total);
            }
        }
   }
Console.WriteLine("\nWant To Add More Item..?? Press Y for Yes or E to End \n");
Console.Write("\nYour Option  : ");
string repeat = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
 if (repeat == "y")
 {
   AddItems(thing);
  }
}
```

Now when the process is repeated **after pressing y**, it is not adding one more item in list **`List<SelectedThing>`**,it shows only one item.

Comment: probably you are passing the new instance of list object to AddItems method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently creating a new list each time you call the method:

```
List<SelectedThing> selectedthing = new List<SelectedThing>();
```

If you want to add new items to the same list then you'll have to pass in that list to the method also. Something like:

```
public void AddItems(List<Things> thing, List<Things> basket)
{
    ....
    ....
    if (repeat == "y")
    {
        AddItems(thing, basket);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any way i can add total of all items added in List . Like instead of showing total for each item.show it for all item.

Answer (score 0):

its because you are creating an instance of list everytime,

```
List<SelectedThing> selectedthing = new List<SelectedThing>();
```

Make it a member variable.

```
List<SelectedThing> selectedthing = new List<SelectedThing>();
public void AddItems(List<Things> thing)
{
    Console.Write("\nEnter Product ID : ");
    int choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("\nEnter Quantity : ");
    int quantity = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    var item = thing.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ID == choice);

    if (item.ID == choice)
    {

        {
            var total = item.Price * quantity;
            selectedthing.Add(new SelectedProduct(this.ID = item.ID, this.Price = item.Price, this.Quantity = quantity, this.Name = item.Name));
            foreach (var items in selectedthing)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nYou Selected {0} and {1} quantity.Total Is {2:C}\n", items.Name, quantity, total);
            }
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\nWant To Add More Item..?? Press Y for Yes or E to End \n");
    Console.Write("\nYour Option  : ");
    string repeat = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
    if (repeat == "y")
    {
        AddItems(thing);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more better approach to `@kjbartel` would be to use both list as ref type in the function, i.e.,

```
public void AddItems(ref List<Things> thing, ref List<Things> basket)
{
    ....
    ....
    if (repeat == "y")
    {
        AddItems(ref thing, ref basket);
    }
}
```

Now the problem of creating to new instance is solved. All the changes are done to same instance.
Hope you would try this.